# Annotatorjs causes Mathjax to fail intermittently

Tags: mathjax, annotatorjs

On a large page with many mathml tags, that also uses annotatorjs the math intermittently reverts to browser rendering, or renders with MathJax, but the context menu does not appear.

Answer (score 1):

Annotator js removes script tags from the document, to avoid them re-running when it wraps the content.
Mathjax stores the original mathml tags code in a script tag with type="math/mathml".

Options include

1. host annotator js yourself and modify the line
   `this.element.find('script').remove();`
   to `this.element.find('script[type!="math/mml"]').remove();`
2. ensure annotator runs completely before mathjax runs.